# Replacing CharField with a ForeignKey based on the CharField

Tags: django, django-models

While refactoring an app, I've started removing a config file and replacing it with a new model, `Foo` in this example. Because of this, another model, `Bar` in this example, needs to change from having a `CharField` that was for the config file, to a `ForeignKey` that is for the new model.

Say I have

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)

class Bar(models.Model):
    name_of_foo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and I want to change `name_of_foo` to instead be a `ForeignKey`...

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=???)
```

I would like the default to be based on what `name_of_foo` was. If `name_of_foo` was "abc", I would like it to do something akin to `default=Foo.objects.get("abc")`.

Is there a way to fill in the `???` such that this works nicely? If not, what steps can I take to arrive here, so that the existing data is converted?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it is possible to achieve what you want using the `default` field but I'll leave it to someone else with more knowledge than me to answer that.

Assuming that a `Foo` object exists for each `Bar` object where `foo.name` = `bar.name_of_foo` you should be able to add a foreign key to `Bar` that links to the Foo object with the following steps.

1. Add foreign key field with `null=True`

```py
class Bar(models.Model):
    name_of_foo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

2. run `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands
3. Open the django shell

```py
python manage.py shell
```

4. run the following code to update the foreign key of each `Bar` object (making changes where necessary)

```py
from <app_name>.models import Foo, Bar

for foo in Foo.objects.all():
    bar = Bar.objects.get(name_of_foo=foo.name)
    bar.foo = foo
    bar.save()
```

5. remove `name_of_foo` field

```py
class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

6. run `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands

Comment: Thanks for the alternate path. I don't know much about custom migrations but I might try putting these ideas here into one. I'll report back after looking into it, might be a bit though since I haven't tried this before =p

Comment: It turns out all the new ForeignKey objects didn't depend on the name, because in my case all the names were the same. I simply ended up just changing the field and adding a default when prompted, so this problem actually didn't come up.

I did however learn to write data migrations for another reason, and I believe this is the way to go here. In Python logic in 1 migration, the column could be replaced how the question described. For anyone who runs into this, see the django docs on data migrations. The logic from this answer could be placed into the data migration quite smoothly